# Catching syntax error and custom error reporting

Tags: slim

I am using slim framework 3 . I am new to this framework. I am working on catching the errors and returning the custom JSON error and message.

I used this code to catch notFoundHandler  error :

```
$container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) { 
    return function ($request, $response) use ($c) { 
        return $c['response'] 
            ->withStatus(404) 
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
            ->write('Page not found'); 
    }; 
};
```

But I am able to catch the normal syntax error. 
It is showing Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in X-api\controllers\Products.php on line 42

Instead of this message, I want my custom error to handle syntax error reporting. 
I used this also,

```
$container['phpErrorHandler'] = function ($c) { 
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) { 
        //Format of exception to return 
        $data = [ 
            'message' => "hello" 
        ]; 
        return $container->get('response')->withStatus($response->getStatus()) 
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
            ->write(json_encode($data)); 
    }; 
};
```

But not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The default error handler can also include detailed error diagnostic information. To enable this you need to set the `displayErrorDetails` setting to true:

```
$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
];
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($c);
```

Note this is not appropriate for production applications, since it may reveal some details you would want not to reveal. You can find more in [Slim docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html).

**EDIT**

If you need to handle `parseErrors`, then you need to define `phpErrorHandler` in your container, just like you did define `notFoundHandler`.

```
$container['phpErrorHandler'] = function ($container) {
    return function ($request, $response, $error) use ($container) {
        return $container['response']
            ->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write('Something went wrong!');
    };
};
```

**Note:** this will work with PHP7+ only, because in older versions parseErrors cannot be catched.

Comment: I have already done this config. But instead of default error handler , I want my custom error handling using slim framework.

Comment: I have already defined phpErrorHandler in my questions too. please see my question

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: Though I have found solution by using `set_error_handler`

Comment: `set_error_handler` is a good solution, but it's kinda beyond Slim. )

Answer (score 0):

I have used this short of code in my dependencies.php

```
$container['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
  return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {  
            $data = [
            'message' => "Syntex error"
            ];          
        return $c['response']
            ->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write(json_encode($data));
    };
};



set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so ignore it
        return;
    }
    throw new \ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
});
```

Now its working for me.